# How to get a list of available offers and the resources they use in Azure RM REST API?

Tags: rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

For the classic Azure model there is a method to get a list of available roles which is described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469422.aspx

`https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/rolesizes`

The method returns a list of offers and resources they use like memory and number of cores.

On Powershell its Get-AzureRoleSizes which outputs a list of elements like this:

> InstanceSize                       : Standard_L8s
>   RoleSizeLabel                      : Standard_L8s (8 cores, 65536 MB)
>   Cores                              : 8
>   MemoryInMb                         : 65536
>   SupportedByWebWorkerRoles          : False
>   SupportedByVirtualMachines         : True
>   MaxDataDiskCount                   : 16
>   WebWorkerResourceDiskSizeInMb      : 0
>   VirtualMachineResourceDiskSizeInMb : 1421312
>   OperationDescription               : Get-AzureRoleSize
>   OperationId                        : 6aae4878-e8f4-7e1a-b434-8fb4dc4fd389
>   OperationStatus                    : Succeeded

I need that information to know how many resources a new VM is going to take before deploying it but using the newer ARM REST API.

Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following API to view available machine sizes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-list-sizes-region